# ODEs simulation issue

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am simulating a set of ODEs in Python, but I am getting this error:
x = odeint(model,x0,t,args=(rim,))
File "C:\Python\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 244, in odeint
int(bool(tfirst)))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Here is my code:

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from gekko import GEKKO
Kg=0.1 
Kd=1.1
kg=0.05 
kd=0.05
ka=0.0455 
Kr=4.5 
Kd=1 
alpha=0.026
beta=0.00075
n=4 
l=4
m0= 2.5
f0= 2.5
p0= 2.5
g0= 2.5
x0 = [m0,f0,p0,g0]
ds = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
ds.columns
rim = ds[1:]
def model(x,t,rim):
    m,f,p,g = x
    m = x[0]
    f = x[1]
    p = x[2]
    g = x[3]
    dmdt = ((kg*(f*g))/(Kg+f))-((m*p)/(1+m))+ rim
    dfdt = -kg*(f*g)/(Kg+f)+(m*p)/(1+m)-(f*p)/(1+f)
    dpdt = (alpha*(f**n)/(Kr**n+f**n)-ka*p**2)
    dgdt = beta*(f**l)/(Kd**l+f**l)-kd*(g*p)/(Kd+g)
    dxdt = [dmdt, dfdt, dpdt, dgdt]
    return dxdt
    
t = np.linspace(0,90000000,20000000)
x = odeint(model,x0,t,args=(rim,))
     
m = x[:,0]
f = x[:,1]
p = x[:,2]
g = x[:,3]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t,f, color='blue', lw=3, label='M')
plt.plot(t,m, color='red',  lw=3, label='F')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('F and M')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(t,p, color='green', lw=3, label='P')
plt.plot(t,g, color='yellow',  lw=3, label='G')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('P and G')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)
plt.subplot(3 ,1,3)
plt.plot(f,m, color='blue', lw=3, label='P')
plt.xlabel('F')
plt.ylabel('M')
plt.show()
```

Can you kindly please help me with solving this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data format in the dataset.csv?

Comment: Consider the dimension of the dataset is, for instance, 45 times 100. Assume the dataset to be random.

Comment: You have `dmdt = ((kg*(f*g))/(Kg+f))-((m*p)/(1+m))+ rim` and `dmdt` is one of the components returned by `model`.  For that to work, `rim` must be a scalar.  I suspect it is a Pandas DataFrame or Series in your code, and the return value of `model` is not a simple sequence of four scalars.

Comment: Thanks Warren for you the info, but rim is a data matrix; let say rim is 16 rows by 30 columns matrix. Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!